# Modify Postgres 9.0 query plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I'm looking for more information how to modify Postgres 9..0 query plan.

I have query:

```
SELECT
    max(creation_date) 
FROM 
    statistics_loged_users 
WHERE
    school_id    = 338 and 
    group_id     = 3 and 
    usr_id       = 243431;
```

And explain analyze output:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=1518.56..1518.57 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=410.459..410.459 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on statistics_loged_users  (cost=993.96..1518.55 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=410.025..410.406 rows=210 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((group_id = 3) AND (usr_id = 243431))"
"        Filter: (school_id = 338)"
"        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=993.96..993.96 rows=133 width=0) (actual time=409.521..409.521 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statistics_loged_users_idx2  (cost=0.00..496.85 rows=26669 width=0) (actual time=375.770..375.770 rows=3050697 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (group_id = 3)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statistics_loged_users_idx  (cost=0.00..496.85 rows=26669 width=0) (actual time=0.077..0.077 rows=210 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (usr_id = 243431)"
"Total runtime: 411.419 ms"
```

We can see that first filter is by group_id.
This table is very very big :)
So there is a lot of rows where group_id is the same, but much less rows with the same usr_id.

Question is how can I tell query plan that first filter must be usr_id.

I create index on group_id and usr_id and I got performance, 
but there I need to know how to modify query plan, it's for future :)

Comment: Estimated rows 26,669, actual 3,050,697. I think `vacuum analyze` is in order.  Do you do that regularly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL planner doesn't really accept hints in the way that you want. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to rewrite your query.

Analysing your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, it's clear that most of the time is spent in the following section:

> "              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on statistics_loged_users_idx2  (cost=0.00..496.85 rows=26669 width=0) (actual time=375.770..375.770 rows=3050697 loops=1)"
>
> "                    Index Cond: (group_id = 3)"

If you rewrite your query in order to first look only for `usr_id` and `school_id` you will get what you want.

```
SELECT
    max(creation_date) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        group_id, creation_date
    FROM
        statistics_loged_users 
    WHERE
        school_id    = 338 and 
        usr_id       = 243431
) AS cd
WHERE 
group_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The current query now has to use two indexes, statistics_loged_users_idx and statistics_loged_users_idx2, a single index might be faster. Create a single index on usr_id, group_id and school_id and try some other column order in the index as well.

Two examples:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_triple_index ON statistics_loged_users(usr_id, group_id, school_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_triple_2_index ON statistics_loged_users(usr_id, school_id, group_id);
```

Give it a try and check EXPLAIN ANALYZE again.

Comment: yep, this does the trick - got more perfomance :) but anyway - is there way to modify plan by setting some parameters how to execute query. For example there(with index on each column, not single index) specify filter index order?